# How to Logout (Session End) of Facebook using objective c?

Tags: iphone

I am using FbGraphAPI for Facebook integration.I am facing problem which is How can i logout from facebook using objective c?In C#, there is method Session.Abondon() which is used for forcefully logout likewise is there any method in objective c or any other way to logout from the account? I am using FbGraph not FBConnect.

Please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to logout from face book use -

```
[facebook logout:self];
```

look in face book class there is a method -

```
- (void)logout:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```